# What is the minimum doctype IE requires to NOT use quirks mode?

Tags: html, sharepoint, doctype, quirks-mode

I am developing for SharePoint 2007 and my pretty code is being broken, presumably by code SharePoint generates around my Content Editor web-part. My understanding is, because there is no "top level" doctype declaration made before SharePoint sends the code to the browser, Internet Explorer is forced to render the page in quirks mode. Thus, the entire page is rendered without respecting certain CSS declarations and my page looks wrong.

I have hopes of convincing the powers that be that this issue is worth fixing, but I figure I need to be able to tell them what I want...

So, what doctype would work best when I'm writing in XHTML (strict) with CSS2 but the stuff surrounding my code is not strict?

Comment: What browsers are you targeting?

Comment: @ knight0323: I'm targeting IE 7 and 8. Firefox renders it fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This declares your document as HTML5, and [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) clearly defines how browsers should handle broken code so your result should look the same on all browsers.

Comment: And this will tell IE 7+ to observe my CSS?

Comment: Yes, it will switch IE6+ and virtually every browser except for Netscape 6 into standard mode. IE7 may not support some of your CSS properties or have bugs in its CSS implementation though.

Comment: @ phihag: I just wanted to thank you for your help... I've put in a request to my IT department to see if they are willing to add the doctype declaration to my SharePoint site's master page.